# MacBook Pro TrackPad - Can you reverse the direction of the swipe?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macbook-pro, touchpad

I have a mid-2010 MacBook Pro, my first Mac and love it.
I would like to be able to two-finger swipe right and the image/display move right, not left... swipe up and the image/display move up, not down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [SmartScroll](http://www.marcmoini.com/sx_en.html) on my MacBook.  It adds a lot of capability, and optionally reversing the scroll axes is one of them.  It can add a number of capabilities, including ballistic scrolling, or coasting, which is what I use it for.  It's not free - $14 - but you can try it free.  Note that you'll probably have to update it (no additional cost) after every OS upgrade, at least with Snow Leopard.  That hasn't been a problem for me - I haven't yet had to wait for them to upgrade it (but then I usually wait a week or two to install new OS releases).

Comment: Many Thanks!Bought it, checked the box to reverse the x and y axis, happy girl! So when are we able to upgrade to Lion?

Comment: You're welcome - I'm glad that solved it for you.  I'd encourage (and request) that you vote best answer for posts that best answer your questions, and (when you have sufficient rep) vote up responses to your or others' questions that you find helpful or enlightening.  Rep is what this community runs on, and represents the degree to which members value one anothers' contributions.  Your contributions will be welcome, too.

Answer (score 0):

BetterTouchTool does it too (and more), for cheaper (currently free). I am just a happy user. http://www.boastr.de/